# Center Headers in Footer to Organize it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was able to find an html and css code to start creating my footer.
I was able to make it look a bit the way I want as seen in the following code:

However, I wanna be able to center all three headers and I can't seem to find how...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.textDecoration {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #24262b;
  padding: 0px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-col {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-col h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-col ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links a:hover {
  color: #24262b;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<p>In this example, we remove the bullets from the list, and its default padding and margin.</p>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer-col">
        <h4>Terms & Conditions</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-col">
        <h4><a class="textDecoration" href="#privacy">Privacy and Policy</a></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="footer-col">
        <h4>Follow Us</h4>
        <div class="social-links">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-col">
        <div class="social-links">
          <h3><img src="https://i.ibb.co/Lp1sB0M/face4.png"></a>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XVzFjBR/ig3.png"></a>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vVRq5dz/tw2.png"></a>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8j8dWcG/yt2.png"></a>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Any hints you can provide me to achieve this?
What would you recommend for social network icons for the footer?

Comment: There are no `headers` in your code. What are you referring to as a header?

Comment: he proberly means the `<h1-6>`tags. However you have an invalid markup. Any IDE should already show that incl. any markup validator. `<img></a>`  is invalid that you sued 4 times. You enevr opened an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to put all `h4`'s in a single `footer-col` div together because you want them grouped in the center. So you can do that, then add `display: flex;` to `footer-col` and use `justify-content: center;` to center them. Then you can add a `gap` to space them out. I also added `display: flex;` on your `social-links` to allow them to flex to stay on the same line.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-links {
  display: flex;
}

.textDecoration {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #24262b;
  padding: 0px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-col {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2em;
}

.footer-col h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-col ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links a:hover {
  color: #24262b;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>In this example, we remove the bullets from the list, and its default padding and margin.</p>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="footer-col">
          <h4>Terms & Conditions</h4>
          <h4><a class="textDecoration" href="#privacy">Privacy and Policy</a></h4>
          <h4>Follow Us</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="social-links"><img src="./img/face4.png">
          <img src="./img/ig3.png">
          <img src="./img/tw2.png">
          <img src="./img/yt2.png">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot.
Look at the image below:
https://ibb.co/cyLw1px
I cant seem to find a way to align the youtube logo, what should I be looking for? How would I move all of them a bit to the top? Margin? Border?
Is there any specific resolution for those type of images I should use?

Comment: editing to mention

Comment: @Erudes edit the question with those images loaded in and I will take a look

Comment: done, so Im looking to move them to the top a bit and maybe reduce the size  withouth them being blurry, I know that can be hard

Comment: @Erudes I would look into getting new logos. Yours seem blurry as is. Once you have 4 new png logos, remove the nesting `h3` and `flex` `social-links`.

Comment: h3 nesting? do you mean h4? I didnt have a flex position in .social links though hehe

Comment: @Erudes No, I mean you have all your images nested in an `h3`.

Comment: just tried it, did not work :( will keep on trying

Comment: I never said that would fix it, just saying you shouldn’t do that semantically. You have to add other styles now to social links class. I’ll answer in a few hours when I’m on my computer if you can update with new images. Your images are blurry already so impossible to fix them by code, maybe photoshop.

Comment: thank you I really appreciate the help, I'll keep tying on my end